# How to get other chords of same key?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

In the key of C major, the C major chord is the first, third and fifth note of the major scale.

In the key of D minor, the D minor chord is the first, third and fifth note of the minor scale.

As you can see, I have figured out how to get **one** chord from each key.

My question is, how do I figure out what other chords are in the scale?

I don't want to learn off some shortcuts like circle of fifths or anything.

I would like to first figure out the raw process of determining the other chords.

I have seen people play the other chords in the key of C, by just shifting their hands from left to right on a piano, but playing the same pattern. But I take it that this is once again a shortcut for the key of C just because a piano happens to be laid out that way. So I'd like to learn about a general way of finding these chords without using a piano. I was thinking you just add one each time, so 1-3-5 becomes 2-4-6, then 3-5-7, but I don't think that's right either.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. 2-4-6 is the second chord (ii), Dm in the key of C. So on from there to get the rest. You'll eventually become very familiar with the I ii iii IV V vi viidim pattern of the major scale that it becomes second nature